# drawing lots of identical features — what's the best approach?

Tags: performance, openlayers-3

I need to draw a large number of rectangles (potentially up to millions), which are located all over the world. I was wondering what the optimal approach is to achieve the best possible performance. my requirements are:

- all items are rectangles (not squares), and identical in size and color
- their rotation is different per individual item though
- they have different fixed locations – they do not move
- the rectangles need to be pickable
- they might need to be scaled according to current zoom level (to make them look like real objects on the ground)
- use the webgl renderer

what I have tried to far:

```
const features = R.map(
    (i) => {
        // [...] calculate `coords` and `rotation`
        const point = new ol.geom.Point(coords);
        const feature = new ol.Feature(point);
        feature.__angle = rotation;
        return feature;
    },
    R.range(0, count /* lots of them! */)
);

const sheetStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
        size: [5, 8], // shape of rectangle
        src: 'color.png' // 1×1px image
    })
});

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({ features }),
    preload: Infinity,
    updateWhileAnimating: true,
    updateWhileInteracting: true,
    style: (feature, resolution) => {
        const image = sheetStyle.getImage();

        // TODO: is there a way to only have to do this once?
        image.setRotation(feature.__angle);

        // scale according to zoom level
        image.setScale(0.3 / resolution);

        return sheetStyle;
    },
});
```

I was wondering if ol3 was doing any sort of optimization under the hood.

- does it merge the geometries into one?
- does it only display items that in the visible part of the map?
- since all items are identical, is there a way to use instancing?

related: for better performance, I am only creating a single style object that I am reusing for all items. however I need to set a rotation on each of them, which is why I am using a style function. once it is set, the rotation won't change anymore though. is there a way around having to call the style function every frame?

I am also considering using a heatmap layer for lower zoom levels and then switching to the vector layer as the user zooms in.

it would be great if someone could give me hints for overall performance improvements.

Comment: Is __angle an integer?  Could you cache your styles using that as the key?  Then you'd have say 360 pre-built styles.

Comment: `__angle` is a random float in my tests so far, but 360 pre-built ones would indeed provide enough variation.